# Как доработать скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }
        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    var deadline="{{ $lot->end_at }}";
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Как сделать чтобы при окончании таймера, содержимое заменялось на `<p>Готово</p>`

```
<div class="timer">
                        <div id="clockdiv" class="mt20">
                            <div class="clock_div">
                                <span class="days"></span>
                                <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clock_div">
                                <span class="hours"></span>
                                <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clock_div">
                                <span class="minutes"></span>
                                <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clock_div">
                                <span class="seconds"></span>
                                <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
}
```

добавить

```
if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
            clock.innerHTML = "<p>Готово</p>";
}
```

html глянуть бы конечно надо было бы

Comment: Добавил код html

Comment: ну попробуйте как написано

Comment: попробовал, не работает

Comment: вместо clock.innerHTML = "<p>Готово</p>"; впишите alert('Готово'); и попробуйте - вылетает алерт по окончанию таймера?

Comment: нет, не выдает(

Comment: а перед clearInterval(timeinterval); поставьте alert('Готово');

Comment: тоже не работает

Comment: а таймер считает вообще? дело в том что по условию  clearInterval останавливает таймер. Это происходит?

Comment: таймер продолжает работать, обновляется и возращает NaN значение. в deadline указано вчерашняя дата

Comment: а тут что
$lot->end_at

Comment: Проблема решена, дело было как раз в переменной $lot->end_at, так как получал неправильный формат даты, ваш первый ответ и был верным решением, благодарю за уделенное время)